# Java - JSONArray has 10 objects but only display first two

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I'm new to Android and Java so I'm building a demo app of book listing to learn about parsing JSON data. I use log to check how many books there are on data (which is 10 ) but only get 2 first books on the list displayed when running it on an emulator... Hope anyone can tell me where I should change? 
Thanks for any opinion!

```
E/QueryUtils: length of array: 10
```

[image: This is the screenshot of the app which shows only two items]

The API link: [https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=search+terms](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=search%20terms)

**QueryUtils.java**

```
 private static List<BookItem> extractItemFromJson(String bookJSON) {
        // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(bookJSON)){
            return null;
        }

    // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding books to
    List<BookItem> bookItems = new ArrayList<>();

    // Try to parse the JSON response string. If there is a problem with the way the JSON is formatted,
    // a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
    // Catch the exception so the app doesnt crash, and prent the error message to the logs.
    try {
        JSONObject baseJsonresponse = new JSONObject(bookJSON);
        JSONArray bookItemArray = baseJsonresponse.getJSONArray("items");
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "length of array: " + bookItemArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < bookItemArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentBook = bookItemArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject volumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
            String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
            String subtitle = volumeInfo.getString("subtitle");
            String previewLink = volumeInfo.getString("previewLink");
            JSONObject imageLinks = volumeInfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
            String thumbnail = imageLinks.getString("smallThumbnail");

            BookItem book = new BookItem(/**author, */title, subtitle, thumbnail, previewLink);
            bookItems.add(book);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
    }

    return bookItems;
}
```

Comment: we can tell, if your question is clear. **only display first two** where ?

Comment: @Ravi only display first two on the main activity on the emulator device when the app is running.. Um, do I make myself clear enough?

Comment: Yes. You need to tell the part of code, which is printing two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third book in your list does not cointain the field `imageLinks`, and that causes an exception.
You should add a check:

```
String thumbnail = "";
if (volumeInfo.has("imageLinks")) {
    JSONObject imageLinks = volumeInfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
    thumbnail = imageLinks.getString("smallThumbnail");
}
```

Comment: yess! Thank you so much.. I forgot the third book would be in position (2) not (3)..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's going to the catch block after parsing the first 2 because an exception happened while parsing, You should fix the exception and also you can catch the exception inside the loop to add the items that could be parsed and don't quit the loop if there is a `JSONException`.

Comment: *because an exception happened while parsing* any specific reason ?

Comment: @Ravi no, just because there can't be another reason I can think of and I know the question should be clearer.

Comment: @AhmedHegazy oh yass, thank you. The log said that there is `no value for imageLinks` .  Understand the original problem and try to figure it out now why there is  no value for imageLinks now... (altho I still haven't found out why it said so)